# ZAP Proxy Java Lib - Is it still usable and maintained?

Tags: java, zap

I have found this link about OWASP ZAP Proxy: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Proxy

And find it very interesting.

I have the need to write a (mitm) server auditing and monitoring web traffic and adding company information in the page in some cases.

Implementing an example like the one described in the above url would be great.

I have also downloaded and used ZAP Proxy. This works like a charm. So I'd like either to be in a position to use ZAP proxy and implement my own request/response modification in Java, or use the code mentioned in the url.

Unfortunately this code seems to have been written 5 years ago. OWASP releases client apis but not this one.

So my question is can I still use the OWASP APIs to intercept and modify the code or should I have a different approach?

I really need to be able to automate the transformation and will need to call company web services for the transformation. So I am not sure scripting is enough. Java would be great.

I guess ZAP Proxy should use these libraries itself. So I am wondering if they are reusable in a standalone java program.

What is your view on this?

Many thanks

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid thats not the ZAP code, and ZAP does not use it in any way.

The ZAP code lives in https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy and is very well maintained :)

However I probably wouldnt recommend using the ZAP code as a basis for a long running server right now - we are improving ZAP so that it can be used like this but there are currently still limitations.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Thank you. Yes the zap proxy branch you mentioned is very well maintained. So what is this code I found on your web site? Would then recommend me to use your scripting engine to industrialise the request/response transformations I need to implement? I need to identify some corporate data and then call an internal web service with these data (Data Leak Prevention). Thanks and regards

Comment: The OWASP Proxy is a different project, one that no longer maintained I'm afraid. I'll admit its a bit confusing :/
Whether you could/should use the ZAP code all depends on your requirements. Might be easier to discuss this on the ZAP developer group? https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-develop

Comment: Thanks. I just posted the question on the group